# Finding the expected value of poisson distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

The number of breakdowns per week for a type of computer is a random variable Y
having a Poisson distribution with mean μ. A random sample Y1; Y2, .... Yn of observations
on the weekly number of breakdowns is available.

The weekly cost of repairing the breakdowns is $C = 3Y +Y^2$.
Show that $\mathbb{E}[C] = 4μ+μ^2$.

Could anyone give me any ideas where to start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $var[Y] = E[Y] = \mu$. Hence $E[Y^2] = var[Y] + E[Y]^2 = \mu + \mu^2$, and the value for $E[C]$ follows.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
{\mathbb E}\bracks{Y}&=\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\expo{-\mu}\mu^{n} \over n!}\,n
=
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\expo{-\mu}\mu^{n} \over \pars{n - 1}!}
=
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\expo{-\mu}\mu^{n + 1} \over n!}
=
\mu\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\expo{-\mu}\mu^{n} \over n!}
=\mu
\end{align}

> \begin{align}
> {\mathbb E}\bracks{Y^{2}}&=\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\expo{-\mu}\mu^{n} \over n!}\,n^{2}
> =
> \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\expo{-\mu}\mu^{n} \over \pars{n - 1}!}\,n
> =
> \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\expo{-\mu}\mu^{n + 1} \over n!}\,\pars{n + 1}
> \\[3mm]&=
> \mu\
> \overbrace{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\expo{-\mu}\mu^{n} \over n!}\,n}
> ^{\ds{{\mathbb E}\bracks{Y} = \mu}}\
> +\
> \mu\
> \overbrace{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\expo{-\mu}\mu^{n} \over n!}}^{\ds{1}}
> =\mu^{2} + \mu
> \end{align}

$$
\color{#00f}{\large{\mathbb E}\bracks{3Y + Y^{2}}} = 3\pars{\mu} + \pars{\mu^{2} + \mu} =
\color{#00f}{\large 4\mu + \mu^{2}}
$$